# How to Change the Pagination Label of the component EuiInMemoryTable from EUI Framework

Tags: css, reactjs, reactiveui, eui

I want to translate the ["Rows per page: " by "Lignes par page : "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DnaI.png) but i don't know how to do it...

This is my code :

```
import React from 'react'

import { EuiInMemoryTable } from "@elastic/eui";
const PAGE_INDEX = 0;
const PAGE_SIZE = 10;

const COLUMNS = [
    {
    field: "nom",
    name: "Nom",
    sortable: "true"
    }
];
const PAGINATION = {
  PAGE_INDEX,
  PAGE_SIZE,
  pageSizeOptions: [10, 25, 50],
  pageSizeLabel: "Lignes par page"
};

const test = [
  {
    nom: "nom 1"
  },
  {
    nom: "nom 2"
  },
  {
    nom: "nom 3"
  },
  {
    nom: "nom 4"
  },
  {
    nom: "nom 5"
  }
];

export const Demo = () => (
  <>
    <EuiInMemoryTable pagination={PAGINATION} columns={COLUMNS} items={test} />
  </>
);
```

I searched things in the official webSite Eui FrameWork and i try to searched on gitHub but nothing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.